# How well can ADSCFT related approaches to condense matter predict measurable properties of materials?

Tags: condensed-matter

Are ADSCFT techniques able to make any predictions about measurable properties of any materials? Are there some interesting but somewhat accessible looking problems left in this area to solve or is the field headed for a decline?

Comment: Are you asking if you are still needed to find a theory of everything? Don't worry, you are not too late to that party, yet. I would even bet that your great-grandchildren won't be too late. :-)